# Sending custom EWS over DAB+ with a HackRF One

Tags: software-defined-radio, software-development

**Disclaimer**: I'm aware of legal issues regarding EWS! Rest assured that there is no need for concern as this is a small-scale, proof of concept done in a controlled enviroment!

Greetings!

I'm trying to send EWS signals over DAB+ with my HackRF One, but I haven't really been able to figure it out yet. Is there someone who has attempted the same and had success?

I have been reading ETSI's [European Standard](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300400_300499/300401/02.01.01_60/en_300401v020101p.pdf) and their [Technical Specification](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101700_101799/101756/02.02.01_60/ts_101756v020201p.pdf). But that doesn't really give examples for implementation. I do however have some vague gist as to how the protocol works after reading those but that's about it.

[There is an existing, open-source project available on Github for sending custom data over DAB+](https://github.com/Opendigitalradio/data-over-dab-example) but that has only gotten me so far. I did however manage to send custom, non-EWS signals over DAB+ but I digress.

After some closer inspection of their project, I did see some recurring things come by such as [FIG](https://github.com/Opendigitalradio/ODR-DabMux/tree/master/src/fig) and FIG0. Having read the ETSI documents, EWS could be enabled if some bit field ([bit field 0 according to ETSI TS 101 700](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101700_101799/101756/02.02.01_60/ts_101756v020201p.pdf)) is turned on by a simple 1 (?). This is as far as my knowledge regarding EWS and DAB+ goes. I was hoping that some other knowledgeable individual has had succes in doing this.

Any kind of input regarding how, whether it's possible with that open-source project, or anything else is greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!